# Getting pdb-style caller information in python

Tags: python, stack, pdb

Let's say I have the following method (in a class or a module, I don't think it matters):

```
def someMethod():
    pass
```

I'd like to access the caller's state at the time this method is called.

`traceback.extract_stack` just gives me some strings about the call stack.

I'd like something like `pdb` in which I can set a breakpoint in `someMethod()` and then type 'u' to go up the call stack and then examine the state of the system then.

Comment: Seems like inspect.currentframe() is a start, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
import inspect

def callMe():
    tag = ''
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    try:
        tag = frame.f_back.f_locals['self']._tag
    finally:
        del frame

    return tag
```